# VPN Client is unable to initiate a connection to the VPN server when the server Firewall does not allow incoming OpenSSH connections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

## Original Question

I have set up an OpenVPN Server and an OpenVPN Client.

The problem is that the client can only initiate a connection when the server firewall allows incoming OpenSSH connections.

These are the server's Firewall rules when the client **is** able to initiate a connection.

```
$ ufw status verbose

To                         Action      From                  
--                         ------      ----                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere              // <---
Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW IN    1194/udp              
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW IN    Anywhere              
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)         // <---
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW IN    1194/udp (v6)         
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)         

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   1194/udp on eth0      
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0      
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   1194/udp (v6) on eth0 
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

After we run `ufw delete allow OpenSSH` on the server, the client **is not** able to initiate a VPN connection

This is the log output that we receive when the client is not able to initiate a connection.

```
$ sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf

...

OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1184 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1557,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1557,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,keydir 0,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
UDP link local: (not bound)
UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
```

**How, if at all, can a client initiate an OpenVPN connection when the VPN server does not allow incoming OpenSSH connections?**

## Edits

This is our client configuration:

```
ca ca.crt
cert vpn_client_01.crt
cipher AES-256-CBC
client
dev tun
key vpn_client_01.key
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
proto udp
remote vpn.xxx.ca 1194
remote-cert-tls server
resolv-retry infinite
tls-auth ta.key 1
verb 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two OpenVPN rules you added allow traffic if the **source port** is `1194`, not the **destination port**. This can have two consequences:

1. Even if the client uses `1194` as its source port, that might change, when passing through a NAT. So the client will be denied access.
2. If someone uses `1194` as source port, he can access all your `UDP` services.

You probably want to add rules on the destination port:

```
ufw allow in on eth0 proto udp to any port 1194
```

As for why the firewall allows OpenVPN access, when OpenSSH is allowed, that's an interesting question: you can add the output of `iptables -nvL ufw-user-input` to the question or check which rule counter is increased when an OpenVPN session is established.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `keydir` (key direction) values do not match. Specify the `--key-direction 1` in your OpenVPN client config and you should be sorted out. The allowable values are 0 and 1.

Comment: That's helpful. The client configuration already has this setting: `tls-auth ta.key 1`, which appears to do the same thing as `--key-direction 1` does. What else, if anything, is missing or necessary?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin does anything change in the log when you specify the key-direction?

Comment: The log is identical on running this: `openvpn --config client.conf --key-direction 1`.

Comment: It turned out to be the Firewall as Piotr wrote.